# C# How can I call multiple POST, GET requests with same cookie via HttpWebRequest?

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, http-post, http-get, multiple-instances

my question is, how can I call multiple requests via HttpWebRequest with same authenticate cookie in C#? I tried a lot of times but for now I dunno how to do it :/

My code is below:

```
        var postData = "method=loginFormAccount&args[0][email]=###&args[0][pass]=###&args[0][cache]=37317&args[]=1";
        var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("###");
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;            

        using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
        {
            stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
        }

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        var cookies = new CookieContainer();
        cookies.Add(response.Cookies);

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@desktop + "\\post.html", new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());

        // =================================== END LOGIN ==================================== \\

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@desktop + "\\cookie.html","");

        foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
        {
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@desktop + "\\cookie.html", true))
            {
                file.WriteLine(cook.ToString());
            }
            // Show the string representation of the cookie.                
        }

        HttpWebRequest requestNext = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("####");
        requestNext.CookieContainer = cookies;
        requestNext.Method = "GET";

        HttpWebResponse responseNext = (HttpWebResponse)requestNext.GetResponse();

        //var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@desktop + "\\get.html", new StreamReader(responseNext.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
```

My main problem is that, cookie which I'm getting is the cookie BEFORE authenticate so I must to do something to get cookie AFTER authenticate.

Comment: Are you sure you are getting the authentication cookie back from the first request?

Comment: Yes, Im sure. I got something. Code works well to this moment `var cookies = new CookieContainer(); cookies.Add(response.Cookies);` application added the cookie to the CookieContainer but it cannot add this CookieContainer to the next request. I write a little function which writing me cookies to the file from first request (this is the working cookie) and the second request (GET) where the request creating new Cookie as if the first was not passed. I dont know why it creating new cookie :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
HttpWebRequest requestNext = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("####");
requestNext.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
```